# How to Center IEEE Copyright at the Bottom of the First Page?

Tags: header-footer, ieeetran

I am new in using LaTex and have been preparing my first LaTex paper for a IEEE conference. I have almost completed my document using LaTex but have been dealing a problem for days which I am not able to center the IEEE copyrigth at the bottom of the first page. It is almost done centering the copyright,xxx-x-xxxx-xxxx-x/xx/\$31.00 \copyright 2018 IEEE, but overriding the rigth column.

Could you please help me how to center it at the bottom of the first page avoiding an override with the right column?

[image]

Here is the full LaTex code, as an example.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Keywords}

%*** CITATION PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{cite}
%*** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***


%\ifCLASSINFOpdf

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

% declare the path(s) where your graphic files are

\graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}

% and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with

% every instance of \includegraphics

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\IEEEpubid{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\ \\[10pt]
        \centering\normalsize{xxx-x-xxxx-xxxx-x/xx/\$31.00 \copyright 2018 IEEE}
\end{minipage}} 


\title{How to Center IEEE Copyright at the Bottom of the First Page}


\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Research Engineer}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{Research and Development Department\\XYZ Company\\}

        \and
        \IEEEauthorblockN{Communication Engineer}
        \IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Engineering\\ABC Company\\}}


% make the title area
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}

This article describes how to use the IEEEtran class
with LATEX to produce high quality typeset papers that are suitable
for submission to the Institute of Electrical and Electronics
Engineers (IEEE). IEEEtran can produce conference, journal
and technical note (correspondence) papers with a suitable choice
of class options. This document was produced using IEEEtran
in journal mode.

\end{abstract}

\vspace*{+1em}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
    Class, IEEEtran, LATEX, paper, style, template.

\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}

WITH a recent IEEEtran class file, a computer running
LATEX, and a basic understanding of the LATEX language,
an author can produce professional quality typeset research
papers very quickly, inexpensively, and with minimal effort.
The purpose of this article is to serve as a user guide of
IEEEtran LATEX class and to document its unique features and
behavior.
This document applies to version 1.8b and later of IEEEtran.
Prior versions do not have all of the features described here.
IEEEtran will display the version number on the user’s console
when a document using it is being compiled. The latest version
of IEEEtran and its support files can be obtained from IEEE’s
web site [1], or CTAN [2]. This latter site may have some
additional material, such as beta test versions and files related
to non-IEEE uses of IEEEtran. See the IEEEtran homepage
[3] for frequently asked questions and recent news about
IEEEtran.

WITH a recent IEEEtran class file, a computer running
LATEX, and a basic understanding of the LATEX language,
an author can produce professional quality typeset research
papers very quickly, inexpensively, and with minimal effort.
The purpose of this article is to serve as a user guide of
IEEEtran LATEX class and to document its unique features and
behavior.
This document applies to version 1.8b and later of IEEEtran.
Prior versions do not have all of the features described here.
IEEEtran will display the version number on the user’s console
when a document using it is being compiled. The latest version
of IEEEtran and its support files can be obtained from IEEE’s
web site [1], or CTAN [2]. This latter site may have some
additional material, such as beta test versions and files related
to non-IEEE uses of IEEEtran. See the IEEEtran homepage
[3] for frequently asked questions and recent news about
IEEEtran.

WITH a recent IEEEtran class file, a computer running
LATEX, and a basic understanding of the LATEX language,
an author can produce professional quality typeset research
papers very quickly, inexpensively, and with minimal effort.
The purpose of this article is to serve as a user guide of
IEEEtran LATEX class and to document its unique features and
behavior.
This document applies to version 1.8b and later of IEEEtran.
Prior versions do not have all of the features described here.
IEEEtran will display the version number on the user’s console
when a document using it is being compiled. The latest version
of IEEEtran and its support files can be obtained from IEEE’s
web site [1], or CTAN [2]. This latter site may have some
additional material, such as beta test versions and files related
to non-IEEE uses of IEEEtran. See the IEEEtran homepage
[3] for frequently asked questions and recent news about
IEEEtran.
WITH a recent IEEEtran class file, a computer running
LATEX, and a basic understanding of the LATEX language,
an author can produce professional quality typeset research
papers very quickly, inexpensively, and with minimal effort.
The purpose of this article is to serve as a user guide of
IEEEtran LATEX class and to document its unique features and
behavior.
This document applies to version 1.8b and later of IEEEtran.
Prior versions do not have all of the features described here.
IEEEtran will display the version number on the user’s console
when a document using it is being compiled. The latest version
of IEEEtran and its support files can be obtained from IEEE’s
web site [1], or CTAN [2]. This latter site may have some
additional material, such as beta test versions and files related
to non-IEEE uses of IEEEtran. See the IEEEtran homepage
[3] for frequently asked questions and recent news about
IEEEtran.
WITH a recent IEEEtran class file, a computer running
LATEX, and a basic understanding of the LATEX language,
an author can produce professional quality typeset research
papers very quickly, inexpensively, and with minimal effort.
The purpose of this article is to serve as a user guide of
IEEEtran LATEX class and to document its unique features and
behavior.
This document applies to version 1.8b and later of IEEEtran.
Prior versions do not have all of the features described here.
IEEEtran will display the version number on the user’s console
when a document using it is being compiled. The latest version
of IEEEtran and its support files can be obtained from IEEE’s
web site [1], or CTAN [2]. This latter site may have some
additional material, such as beta test versions and files related
to non-IEEE uses of IEEEtran. See the IEEEtran homepage
[3] for frequently asked questions and recent news about
IEEEtran.


\end{document}
```

Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: You should not give the copyright of your work to IEEE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left off the [t].  \IEEEpubid aligns the first (blank) line with the bottom of the text area.  The default is [c] which would align the center of the minipage with the bottom of the text area.

```
\IEEEpubid{\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\ \\[10pt]
        \centering\normalsize{xxx-x-xxxx-xxxx-x/xx/\$31.00 \copyright 2018 IEEE}
```

Working version:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Keywords}

\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

%*** CITATION PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{cite}
%*** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***


%\ifCLASSINFOpdf

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

% declare the path(s) where your graphic files are

\graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}

% and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with

% every instance of \includegraphics

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\IEEEpubid{\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\ \\[10pt]
        \centering\normalsize{xxx-x-xxxx-xxxx-x/xx/\$31.00 \copyright 2018 IEEE}
\end{minipage}} 


\title{How to Center IEEE Copyright at the Bottom of the First Page}


\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Research Engineer}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{Research and Development Department\\XYZ Company\\}

        \and
        \IEEEauthorblockN{Communication Engineer}
        \IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Engineering\\ABC Company\\}}


% make the title area
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}

This article describes how to use the IEEEtran class with LATEX to produce high quality typeset papers that are suitable for submission to the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE). IEEEtran can produce conference, journal and technical note (correspondence) papers with a suitable choice of class options. This document was produced using IEEEtran in journal mode.

\end{abstract}

\vspace*{+1em}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
    Class, IEEEtran, LATEX, paper, style, template.

\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}

WITH a recent IEEEtran class file, a computer running LATEX, and a basic understanding of the LATEX language, an author can produce professional quality typeset research papers very quickly, inexpensively, and with minimal effort. The purpose of this article is to serve as a user guide of IEEEtran LATEX class and to document its unique features and behavior. This document applies to version 1.8b and later of IEEEtran. Prior versions do not have all of the features described here. IEEEtran will display the version number on the user’s console when a document using it is being compiled. The latest version of IEEEtran and its support files can be obtained from IEEE’s web site 1, or CTAN [2]. This latter site may have some additional material, such as beta test versions and files related to non-IEEE uses of IEEEtran. See the IEEEtran homepage [3] for frequently asked questions and recent news about IEEEtran.

WITH a recent IEEEtran class file, a computer running LATEX, and a basic understanding of the LATEX language, an author can produce professional quality typeset research papers very quickly, inexpensively, and with minimal effort. The purpose of this article is to serve as a user guide of IEEEtran LATEX class and to document its unique features and behavior. This document applies to version 1.8b and later of IEEEtran. Prior versions do not have all of the features described here. IEEEtran will display the version number on the user’s console when a document using it is being compiled. The latest version of IEEEtran and its support files can be obtained from IEEE’s web site 1, or CTAN [2]. This latter site may have some additional material, such as beta test versions and files related to non-IEEE uses of IEEEtran. See the IEEEtran homepage [3] for frequently asked questions and recent news about IEEEtran.

WITH a recent IEEEtran class file, a computer running LATEX, and a basic understanding of the LATEX language, an author can produce professional quality typeset research papers very quickly, inexpensively, and with minimal effort. The purpose of this article is to serve as a user guide of IEEEtran LATEX class and to document its unique features and behavior. This document applies to version 1.8b and later of IEEEtran. Prior versions do not have all of the features described here. IEEEtran will display the version number on the user’s console when a document using it is being compiled. The latest version of IEEEtran and its support files can be obtained from IEEE’s web site 1, or CTAN [2]. This latter site may have some additional material, such as beta test versions and files related to non-IEEE uses of IEEEtran. See the IEEEtran homepage [3] for frequently asked questions and recent news about IEEEtran. WITH a recent IEEEtran class file, a computer running LATEX, and a basic understanding of the LATEX language, an author can produce professional quality typeset research papers very quickly, inexpensively, and with minimal effort. The purpose of this article is to serve as a user guide of IEEEtran LATEX class and to document its unique features and behavior. This document applies to version 1.8b and later of IEEEtran. Prior versions do not have all of the features described here. IEEEtran will display the version number on the user’s console when a document using it is being compiled. The latest version of IEEEtran and its support files can be obtained from IEEE’s web site 1, or CTAN [2]. This latter site may have some additional material, such as beta test versions and files related to non-IEEE uses of IEEEtran. See the IEEEtran homepage [3] for frequently asked questions and recent news about IEEEtran. WITH a recent IEEEtran class file, a computer running LATEX, and a basic understanding of the LATEX language, an author can produce professional quality typeset research papers very quickly, inexpensively, and with minimal effort. The purpose of this article is to serve as a user guide of IEEEtran LATEX class and to document its unique features and behavior. This document applies to version 1.8b and later of IEEEtran. Prior versions do not have all of the features described here. IEEEtran will display the version number on the user’s console when a document using it is being compiled. The latest version of IEEEtran and its support files can be obtained from IEEE’s web site 1, or CTAN [2]. This latter site may have some additional material, such as beta test versions and files related to non-IEEE uses of IEEEtran. See the IEEEtran homepage [3] for frequently asked questions and recent news about IEEEtran.

\end{document}
```